# How to adjust charts in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-learn

How to fix this problem?
Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "C:\Users\Vrushab PC\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\formatters.py", line 307, in __call__
    return printer(obj)

  File "C:\Users\Vrushab PC\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\pylabtools.py", line 240, in <lambda>
    png_formatter.for_type(Figure, lambda fig: print_figure(fig, 'png', **kwargs))

  File "C:\Users\Vrushab PC\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\pylabtools.py", line 124, in print_figure
    fig.canvas.print_figure(bytes_io, **kw)

  File "C:\Users\Vrushab PC\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backend_bases.py", line 2252, in print_figure
    **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\Vrushab PC\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py", line 545, in print_png
    FigureCanvasAgg.draw(self)

  File "C:\Users\Vrushab PC\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py", line 459, in draw
    self.renderer = self.get_renderer(cleared=True)

  File "C:\Users\Vrushab PC\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py", line 476, in get_renderer
    self.renderer = RendererAgg(w, h, self.figure.dpi)

  File "C:\Users\Vrushab PC\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py", line 93, in __init__
    self._renderer = _RendererAgg(int(width), int(height), dpi, debug=False)

ValueError: Image size of 8804752x396 pixels is too large. It must be less than 2^16 in each direction.
```

Comment: 8804752x396 pixels?? You will need a Ultra panoramic screen to visualize this image!!

Answer (score 1):

I think the error code is very clear: the image you are trying to plot is way to big. You have to reduce the size of the image, i.e. you have to scale it down.
What are you even trying to plot which has a size of `8804752x396`? Are you sure, that you did nothing wrong before? This seems to be very huge.

Edit: If you just want to save the image as a `png` or something like this, you try to change the backend to something else - look [here](https://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#what-is-a-backend) for better suited backends for your task and try them!

Comment: I was trying my friends code. In his machine it doesnt give any errors. It works with exactly the same code